# how can i send registration activation link email from my custom domain email (activate@tiguh.com) using php

Tags: php, email, cpanel

i am working on a project (PHP) that allows online registration to access the authenticated only services provided. i want to send the activation link to their email from my custom email address (activate@tiguh.com). can please help me guys. language is (PHP)

i have cpanel access
mail() is not working
[i have tried mail() in another cpanel (another subdomain) it works. i asked the host provider why mail() is not working in my domain and he replies me with the below image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVBRY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you need to get SMTP server
you can by it
requirements:
SMTP server
SMTP user
SMTP pass
SMTP port

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).